# Why doesn't my function recognize a value in an array after I update my if statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the data of a contact when the name actually exist in my array and when it doesn't an "No such contact" prompt, and like this it works and I get "Vos"

```
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property"
        }
    }
  } 
}

lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

But when I add and extra else if it just doesn't recognize the name any more and I get the "No such contact". I guess is something really simple and kind of obvious, but I just don't get why

```
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property"
        }
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName[name] === undefined) {
        return "No such contact"
    }
  } 
}

lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

Comment: Why not step through the execution of that code with your browser's debugger to understand why this is happening?

Comment: firstName is a string and doesn't have a name property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are returning from the loop after the first iteration in the second snippet. As such, you are only checking the first item and then returning 'No such contact'. It looks like you only want to return at the very end if not contact has been found. I have added a console log that shows how many iteration the loop goes through, which should help with troubleshooting.

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    console.log('Loop: ' + i);
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property"
        }
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName[name] === undefined) {
        return "No such contact"
    }
  } 
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```